# How to install new spark version , Without to remove the current installed spark version

Tags: linux, apache-spark, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

we have hortonworks hadoop cluster with spark version - `2.3.0` ( based on HDP `2.6.5` ), with ambari platform

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

in order to upgrade the spark version to `2.3.2` , we need to upgrade the HDP version to `3.1`

but upgrade HDP to `3.1` in order to get spark `2.3.2` is too risky because this is production hadoop cluster

so we decided to install from scratch the spark clients ( from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html ) , on all machines to spark version - `2.4.4` , and leave the old spark version - `2.3.0` as is

means not removed the current spark version , but install new spark version - `2.4.4` ( from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html ) , that will be new working spark instead of spark `2.3.0`

is it possible ?

if yes then how ? ,  procedure?

***Official Apache component versions for HDP 3.1.0:***

```
Apache Accumulo 1.7.0
Apache Atlas 1.1.0
Apache Calcite 1.16.0
Apache DataFu 1.3.0
Apache Hadoop 3.1.1
Apache HBase 2.0.2
Apache Hive 3.1.0
Apache Kafka 2.0.0
Apache Knox 1.0.0
Apache Livy 0.5.0
Apache Oozie 4.3.1
Apache Phoenix 5.0.0
Apache Pig 0.16.0
Apache Ranger 1.2.0
Apache Spark 2.3.2   <------------------
Apache Sqoop 1.4.7
Apache Storm 1.2.1
Apache TEZ 0.9.1
Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0
Apache ZooKeeper 3.4.6
Apache Superset 0.23.3
Apache Druid 0.12.1
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, as long as you need only the Spark runtime for jobs, and not the HistoryServer or ThriftServer _(would be possible too but more complex)_ -- and you don't need to start jobs from Oozie _(building an Oozie ShareLib for Spark seems to be as complicated as building a spaceship...)_. Just install manually the Spark package on the Edge Node from which you will submit the jobs, and setup manually the conf in its private `spark-env.sh`./ `spark-defaults.conf`. Setting env variables `SPARK_HOME` and/or `SPARK_CONF_DIR` may help.

Comment: @Samson , why not the HistoryServer?

Comment: (a) Hopefully your existing 2.3 HistoryServer can manage the logs from your Spark 2.4 jobs, and (b) without Ambari to setup/start/stop/monitor HS you would need to setup a Linux service with custom monitoring and alerting tools... possibly with a manually provisioned Kerberos SPN... also (c) running extra service instances is largely a waste of RAM and CPU

Comment: I will appreciate if you post an answer it will be usful instead of comments

Comment: Generally speaking, the HortonWorks forum (now dumped into the Cloudera forum) is (was) a good place to search for instructions about HortonWorks topics - e.g. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Steps-to-install-supplementary-Spark-on-HDP-cluster/ta-p/244199 >> although in that case the instructions are somewhat confused and confusing... use with caution.

Comment: the problem is that hortonworks questions isn't answered ( I think because the migration )